# look up values for formula in another table by checking date is within start and end date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following staff salary table called **EmployeeSalaryTbl**:

[image: Staff Salaries]

and a table called **EmployersNIContributionTbl** with the following tax information:

[image: Tax]

and I'm looking to create a formula to calculate the associated Employers NI Monthly based on their Salary Start Date that will replicate this pseudo code:

(Salary Monthly-Secondary Threshold) * Employers Contribution %

Where Salary Monthly is the row entry in **EmployeeSalaryTbl** and the Secondary Threshold and Employers Contribution % are from **EmployersNIContributionTbl**.

How would I go about finding the matching row from the employee start date where the start date is within the Tax Period Start Date and Tax Period End Date in the table **EmployersNIContributionTbl**?

Comment: Because you are trying to find a numeric result with criteria, try using SUMIFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the commented suggestion wasn't enough, here's another solution:

```
=([@[Salary Monthly]]-FILTER(EmployersNIContributionTbl[Secondary Threshold], ([@[Salary Start Date]]>=EmployersNIContributionTbl[Tax Period Start Date])*([@[Salary Start Date]]<=EmployersNIContributionTbl[Tax Period End Date])))*FILTER(EmployersNIContributionTbl[Employers Contribution %], ([@[Salary Start Date]]>=EmployersNIContributionTbl[Tax Period Start Date])*([@[Salary Start Date]]<=EmployersNIContributionTbl[Tax Period End Date]))
```